# Tomcat webapps dir

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I have eclipse installed and I installed Tomcat from there. I created an app with eclipse and it runs fine. I know that there are examples in the webapps dir under Tomcat, but they dont run. I think there is a path that was created by eclipse when I downloaded it to point to one webapps folder but I want the default.
I found this:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

but its not helping me.
MY app that runs is in "C:\Users\mike\workspace\HelloMike"
I'm sure this is a simple config, but I'm new at this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse WTP create a .metadata-based `CATALINA_BASE` and will deploy your app to that directory when you hit deploy.

Comment: Mike, this is what I get on startup, But my app that works is not in there and the ones that are , dont work. Using CATALINA_BASE:   C:\Users\mike\Tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   C:\Users\mike\Tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: C:\Users\mike\Tomcat\temp
Using JRE_HOME:        C:\Windows
Using CLASSPATH:       C:\Users\mike\Tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar

Comment: Wait, did you start Tomcat from within Eclipse WTP or with the bundled Windows service launcher?

Comment: I've done both..being the hack that I am..Whats the difference?, That's probably important

Comment: I've started it with Eclipse and with the bat file in bin.

Comment: Use the WTP built-in Tomcat launcher and don't fiddle with the batch file. Use Google.